# maven plugin - throwing Build Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I am facing the below error while I am importing a plugin to the eclipse, using existing Maven Project option.

> Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:3.2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:jar:3.2.3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I am using sdk 3.2.3 & JIRA 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Atlassian Maven repository to your project, or your local Maven repository manager. Refer to [Atlassian documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Maven+Repositories) for repository URLs. As far as I can see the maven-jira-plugin is [there](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-jira-plugin/).